# Inconsistent result from .over operation in python polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a table that contains id and date columns with the date column as pl.Date data type. My goal is to replace every row for each id with its minimum date and find the number of rows that are missing in the date column.

From this table:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2010 |
| 1 | 01-02-2020 |
| 2 | 01-03-2010 |
| 2 | 01-04-2010 |
| 3 | None |
| 3 | None |
| 4 | None |
| 4 | 01-05-2010 |

Into this table:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2010 |
| 1 | 01-01-2010 |
| 2 | 01-03-2010 |
| 2 | 01-03-2010 |
| 3 | None |
| 3 | None |
| 4 | 01-05-2010 |
| 4 | 01-05-2010 |

This example table contains 2 missing data in the date column.

I applied the .over method into larger table (more than 1000+ rows) as shown below:

`df.select(pl.col('date').min().over('id'))['date'].is_null().sum()`

Here, I execute the code above multiple times consecutively, the missing data show incorrect results. The results show an inconsistent number of missing data in each run as shown in the image.

[inconsistent result in each run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Ueo.png)

I tried to convert the data to pandas and use .transform method the result was correct. According to pandas, the number of missing data in the date column is 29,436 rows.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Nugliar, I tried reproducing the error but I was not able to. 
Running your dataset 1000 times always returns the correct number of null rows. 

Which version of Polars are you running?
Also- is it possible to share a bigger dataset that still gives you the problem?

Comment: Hi @Luca. I have uploaded the sample data in .csv format in google drive: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N7cPUq_AgGehMGL-0BuijkOTh6l2D4x5/view?usp=share_link). The Polar's version I'm using is '0.15.16'.

I have tried this following code and mine still have the inconsistent result.
`(pl.read_csv('sample.csv').with_columns(pl.col('date').str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').cast(pl.Date).min().over('id'))['date'].is_null().sum())`

Comment: With this new file, I can also reproduce the error. By launching the calculation 1000 times it's wrong 9 times. The problem seems to be with ids 28 and 93 that only have null values. in some cases the null vales are converted to 1970-01-01.

I think it's worth posting about the issue on the Polars github: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues and attaching the file

Comment: @Luca Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will post the issue there.